# Media player with mouse-selectable subtitles (for copy and paste)

Tags: windows, gratis, media-player, closed-captions

Could you help me to find a free media player for Windows which allows to select and copy a part of subtitles during watching a video?

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made the media player [LLG-MP](https://github.com/engMaher/LLG-MP):

> it's main purpose is to gamify the language learning process through appending clickable subtitles/lyrics to different types of local/remote media with an onclick instant translation during the media stream flow